# How to join an pivot in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a following `table1`

```
id name
1  A
3  B
```

and `table2`

```
id label value
1  tag   a
1  time  10
1  time  15
1  score 20
2  tag   b
2  time  30
2  score 40
2  score 45
3  tag   c
3  time  50
3  score 60 
3  score 65
```

I'd like to join them like following. it need to pivot them
My desired result is following

```
id name time score
1  A    10    20
1  A    15    20
3  B    50    60
3  B    50    65
```

I tried like following.

```
select 
id,
name,
decode(table2.label,time,value) as time,
decode(table2.label,score,value) as score
from table1
left join table2 using(id)
```

it returned like

it is slightly different from my desired result,
Where is wrong point of that ?
If someone has opinion, please let me know
thanks

```
id name time score
1  A     10  
1  A     15
1  A          20
3  B     50
3  B          60
3  B          65
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use pivoting logic:

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.label = 'time'  THEN t2.value END) AS time,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.label = 'score' THEN t2.value END) AS score
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
GROUP BY
    t1.id,
    t1.name;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I checked my data, actually, in `table2` there is duplicated data. I edited my question to reflect them. when I set `max` function, these data will be vanished... sorry for inconvenience. Thanks

Comment: I won't attempt to modify my answer, but it isn't clear what the rules are for your updated data.  If you really have this duplication problem, you should resolve it first by adding a new key which makes every tuple in the second table uniquely identifiable.